# Hello, I have a question about Google sheet API quota

Tags: google-sheets-api

First, I'd like to say truly thank you for all your services.
What I want to ask about Google sheet API quota is about "request per user".
Presently, I am managing a web app for educational calculation built with flutter framework and I successfully connected the app and google sheet with API service. Technically, the app is using one API key, however many other students are using the app same time in classroom. So, here is the point. Does the user in "request per user" mean API key? or each device? If it is the API key, quota is not enough. If it means each device, I guess the quota is sufficient for my case.

Your reply would be very appreciated,  thank you in advance:)

Comment: Your app calls the API, your app is the user. Users or devices that use your application don't matter, because they don't work with the API, your app does. So yes, it means the number of requests from each API key

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. Just one more for little bit more detail. So the user in "request per user" means each app put together which uses same API key, right?

Comment: Think about it from the point of view of Google Sheet service. They remember every API key they give to all the people on the planet. By sending them the API key, *you* verify that you is you, and Google Sheet provides you the service. It doesn't matter if you specify the API key from different devices, from different instances of your program. What matters is that Google Sheet counts every time someone requests something with the same API key. If there are too many requests with the same API key, the next requests will be rejected

Comment: I really appreciate your explanation in detail. Thank you :)